# Retrieve data from elasticsearch using .Dotnet Nest queries and filtering as "Contains"

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have the following code:

```
public async Task<ICollection<Concert>> GetAsync(string? filter, int page, int rows)
    {
        var skip = (page - 1) * rows;

        var searchResponse = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<Concert>(s => s
            .From(skip)
            .Size(rows)
            .Query(q => q
                .MatchPhrase(m => m
                    .Field(f => f.Title)
                    .Query(filter)
                )
            )
        );

        return searchResponse.Documents.ToList();
    }
```

I have 3 indices with the Title "Bob Marley", "Bob Marley1", and "Bob Marley2". However if I  send the filter as "Bob Marley" it doesn't return any data. It seems to be an issue with the space character because when I send "Bob" as the filter, then the data is retrieved. I'm expecting to send any filter, then match all the indices that contains that word or phrase

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have space in indexname. Please check out [this official document for naming rules of elasticsearch index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html#indices-create-api-path-params):

> Index names must meet the following criteria:
>
> - Lowercase only
> - Cannot include `\`, `/`, `*`, `?`, `"`, `<`, `>`, `|`,   (***space character***), `,`, `#`
> - Indices prior to 7.0 could contain a colon (`:`), but that’s been
>   deprecated and won’t be supported in 7.0+
> - Cannot start with `-`, `_`, `+`
> - Cannot be `.` or `..`
> - Cannot be longer than 255 bytes (note it is bytes, so multi-byte
>   characters will count towards the 255 limit faster)
> - Names starting with `.` are deprecated, except for hidden indices and
>   internal indices managed by plugins

Use the following command to list all indices of elasticsearch

```
curl localhost:9200/_cat/indices
```